# The RadioGroup object does not send Touch to the activity

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, radio-group

In an activity with a RadioGroup and 4 RadioButtons, touch input on the RadioGroup is not being propagated to the Activity's onTouch override.  The goal is to have fling gestures work for the entire screen where the RadioGroup is the largest object and is found in the center.

I tried to set a touch listener on the radio group in the activity and that had no effect. I also tried a RadioGroup subclass.  In the subclass I set the class both to be a touch listener, and to override the default onTouchEvent method. I called setOnTouchListener in the constructor.  The subclass behaved exactly the same way.  None of these worked.  There are no error messages.

Has anyone been able to get Touch input on a RadioGroup to go beyond having that touch select a radio button?  Let me know if you want to see the code.  It's real simple.  The activity call to onTouch returns the gesture detector's result.  This works great on the other objects on the screen (TextSwitcher, Relative Layout with 2 buttons).  Why doesn't RadioGroup work?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions to make the RadioGroup work as I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

My new tumbleweed badge makes me think that others do not see this behavior with a Radio Group. It is, perhaps, intermittent behavior.  Another possibility is that it is a problem specific to my Evo testing device.

If others see a similar issue, please add on to this article.